# SCRIPT70: Permission denied on JQuery Ajax Post

Tags: jquery, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, jquery-ajaxq

I've encountered this weird error lately. Here's the flow of the entire process.

1. There is a JQuery ajax post call to a website that will refresh the contents of a div. It will pass in the parameters to that website and will return the HTML script.
2. If the post is successful, it will first clear the div and rewrite it using the return value that was retrieved from that website.

The error occurred on point 2.

Here's the weird thing:

In my machine it is working fine (Windows 8) and also in the virtual machine (Windows 10). I used the same browser (IE 11 and Edge) for both. However, my colleague was not able to do  point 2 because he got the client side error **SCRIPT70: Permission denied.** He was using Edge.

I will post part of the code in my next update. But so far I've checked it in terms of security but none really.

How do I resolve this?

**UPDATE**

Here's the code that calls one website (or aspx) via JQuery Ajax Post, and retrieves and updates the div.

```
function RefreshDiv(isChild) {
  var data = {
    ActionType: "AJAX",
    Action: "Refresh"
  };

  $.post("RefreshDivContents.aspx", data, function (result) {
    if(result != '') {
      var divItems;

      if(isChild) {
          divItems = window.parent.$("#TopDiv").find("#DivItems");
      }
      else {
          divItems = $("#DivItems");
      }

      divItems.empty(); // error hit here.
      divItems.append(result);
    }
  });
}
```

**UPDATE #2**
I updated the sample code for more information. Also, I placed where the error occurred but I don't know why it hit there. It should clear out the items only.

**UPDATE #3**
Based on Jacob's reply, I got curious as to what is the protocol and port numbers of the two iframe src's. Below is the result based on the console.

[image]

Comment: What URL is your friend using? These types of errors are frequently caused by things like attempts to make cross-domain requests or trying to do Ajax from a `file://` URL. You should collect more details on what the difference is between how your colleague is running the code vs. how you are. There may also be differing browser security settings as well.

Comment: It's a web application wherein it is calling one of the aspx pages.

Comment: On the same domain or on a different domain?

Comment: It is on the same domain.

Comment: @Jacob, I updated the question. I hope you can take a look at this. I just find it weird that when it hits the `.empty()`, it will throw the `SCRIPT70` error.

Comment: I have tried to normalize indentation in your code and noticed you're missing the `)` for the `$.post(...)` call (it should be after the `}` on the second-to-last line); maybe the syntax error is causing browsers to interpret the code differently. If that syntax error is there in real life, I'd try fixing it and see if the problem is also fixed.

Comment: sorry, i mistyped that.

Answer (score 1):

This looks problematic:

```
divItems = window.parent.$("#TopDiv").find("#DivItems");
```

I take it from this snippet that the key issue is with [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). A document in one origin cannot update content in another. For example, in this case it looks like your code may be running in an `iframe` and trying to update divs in the parent document. If the two documents have the same origin, there's no problem.

This is why I'd asked about URLs. It's essential to consider what the URLs are for the two documents to find a solution to get the script working:

If it's a matter of document A being from `http://example.com` and document B being from `http://www.example.com`, document B merely has to run `document.domain = 'example.com';` to change origins.

If the two documents have different port numbers but the same domain & protocol, they can both set their `document.domain` to the same domain to scrub away the port number from their origins, making them compatible.

If one uses HTTPS and the other uses HTTP, then it's surprising that the non-secure frame loaded at all, and even if it did, you'll have a hard time accessing the other document.

If the two have utterly incompatible domain names, you'll have to implement [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

To summarize, you need to understand the same-origin policy which is a real pain but protects users from malicious scripts, then build your app to accommodate it.

Comment: I actually tried to add the url to the trusted sites in the internet options but it still hits the error in Edge. Would you have any ideas for this?

Comment: however, i still find it weird because the two files are in the same folder and in the same domain.

Comment: The files don't matter, nor whether the sites are trusted; what are the actual URLs of the documents? That's what matters.

Comment: I also tried to set the parent iframe src to have the full URL and also when I call the jquery post but still it does not work.

Comment: That's curious. I found this old jQuery bug which still may be relevant; maybe it's a jQuery issue: https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14535